# Copy existing jenkins configuration to a new jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins, suse

I'm new to Jenkins and havnig trouble with some basic tasks. 
I have a configured Jenkins on my `Linux SUSE VM` with several installed plugins and important jobs. I'd like to make a `new VM(also SUSE)` with another Jenkins on it with the same configuration and jobs as the existing Jenkins. So basically my goal is to entirely copy the existing Jenkins instance's functionality. Also I'd like to automate this process with `Ansible` later on. What is the easiest way to move existing Jenkins configurations and jobs to make the new instance behave like the old one?

What I've tried already:

1. archived existing jenkins home directory
2. created a new instance of jenkins on the other VM
3. transferred the archived home dir, extracted and replaced it with the new one's home directory

I think some steps are missing as when I start the new Jenkins, it's status is active(exited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [backup/restore](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) procedure from Jenkins works for me. Did you tried it?